# async_graphql::Response: Reply is not satisfied when using warp

Tags: rust, graphql, warp

I'm trying to put together a basic GraphQL server with async-graphql and warp:

```
use async_graphql::{Object, Schema, EmptyMutation, EmptySubscription, Response, Context};
use std::convert::Infallible;
use warp::{Filter};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let schema = Schema::build(Query, EmptyMutation, EmptySubscription).finish();

    // schema processor
    let graphql_api = async_graphql_warp::graphql(schema).and_then(
        |(schema, request): (
            Schema<Query, EmptyMutation, EmptySubscription>,
            async_graphql::Request,
        )| async move { Ok::<_, Infallible>(Response::from(schema.execute(request).await)) },
    );

    let routes = graphql_api;
    warp::serve(routes).bind(([0,0,0,0], 3000)).await;
}

pub struct Book {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    author: String,
}

#[Object]
impl Book {
    async fn id(&self) -> &str {
        &self.id
    }

    async fn name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }

    async fn author(&self) -> &str {
        &self.author
    }
}
struct Query;

#[Object]
impl Query {
    async fn books(&self, _ctx: &Context<'_>) -> Vec<Book> {
        vec![new_book("id1", "Penturian", "Gibsons"), new_book("id2", "Dekatos", "Gibsons")]
    }
}

fn new_book(id: &str, name: &str, author: &str) -> Book {
    Book { id: id.to_string(), name: name.to_string(), author: author.to_string()}
}
```

I get a compile error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `async_graphql::Response: Reply` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:17
   |
22 |     warp::serve(routes).bind(([0,0,0,0], 3000)).await;
   |                 ^^^^^^ the trait `Reply` is not implemented for `async_graphql::Response`
   | 
  ::: /Users/stephen.gibson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.3.1/src/server.rs:26:17
   |
26 |     F::Extract: Reply,
   |                 ----- required by this bound in `serve`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Reply` for `(async_graphql::Response,)`
```

This does not make a lot of sense to me.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "graphql"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
async-graphql = "2.0"
async-graphql-warp = "2.0"
tokio = { version = "1.0.2", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
warp = "0.3"
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde = "1.0"
futures = "0.3"
```

Comment: Why do you believe that `async_graphql::Response` is valid to return from a web request?

Comment: This is what they have in their example for warp integration.  https://github.com/async-graphql/examples/blob/45b58bf1ce53ad76275d3d29c011e37de00e3bb7/warp/starwars/src/main.rs

Comment: Dang!  I had the wrong import.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong import.  I was importing async_graphql::Response but not async_graphql_warp::Response.